# Summation of function's derivate

Tags: functional-analysis, summation, normed-spaces

Does this summation be finite:
$$\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} \int_{[a,b]}\left(\frac{d^l}{dx^l} f(x)\right)^2 dx.$$
obliviously if $f(x)$ is a polynomial the property it's ok, but for regular continuos functions?
Can we extend this for multivariate functions with partial derivates?
It's a quasi-norm?

Answer (score 1):

The sum need not be finite. Consider $f(x)=e^x$. Then each term in your sum is the same positive constant.